# Dart: 'map' called on empty list throws NoSuchMethodError: 'map" Dynamic call of null

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I'm writing simple Flutter project.
When I try to map from JSON to my object I get an error:

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building FutureBuilder<bool>(dirty, state: _FutureBuilderState<bool>#91495):
'map'
Dynamic call of null.
Receiver: "[]"
Arguments: [Instance of '(dynamic) => Task']
```

I have a list of `Project` objects, that contains some values and a list of `Task` objects.
I have empty project, that I load to my "add project" page, modify it.

```dart
Project proj = Project(
      projDeadline: DateTime.now(),
      projDesc: 'description...',
      projIsDone: false,
      projProgress: 0.0,
      projTasks: [],
      projTitle: 'empty project');
```

After that I encode it to Json and put in local storage with these functions"

```dart
_saveToStorage() {
    storage.setItem('projects', sprojs.toJson());
  }

  _addProject(Project proj) {
    setState(() {
      sprojs.items.add(proj);
      _saveToStorage();
    });
  }
```

`sprojs` is of type `ProjectList` that contains only a list of projects and some methods.
These are all my classes:

```dart
class Task {
  String taskTitle;
  String taskDesc;
  bool taskIsDone;
  List<String> taskTags;
  double taskProgress;

  Task(
      {required this.taskTitle,
      required this.taskDesc,
      required this.taskIsDone,
      required this.taskTags,
      required this.taskProgress});

  factory Task.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson) {
    return Task(
        taskTitle: parsedJson['taskTitle'],
        taskDesc: parsedJson['taskDesc'],
        taskIsDone: parsedJson['taskIsDone'],
        taskProgress: parsedJson['taskProgress'],
        taskTags: List<String>.from(parsedJson['taskTags']));
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      "taskTitle": this.taskTitle,
      "taskProgress": this.taskProgress,
      "taskDesc": this.taskDesc,
      "taskIsDone": this.taskIsDone,
      "taskTags": jsonEncode(this.taskTags)
    };
  }
}

class Project {
  String projTitle;
  DateTime projDeadline;
  double projProgress;
  String projDesc;
  bool projIsDone;
  List<Task> projTasks;

  Project(
      {required this.projTitle,
      required this.projDeadline,
      required this.projProgress,
      required this.projDesc,
      required this.projIsDone,
      required this.projTasks});

  factory Project.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson) {
    return Project(
        projTitle: parsedJson['projTitle'],
        projDeadline: DateTime.parse(parsedJson['projDeadline']),
        projProgress: parsedJson['projProgress'],
        projDesc: parsedJson['projDesc'],
        projIsDone: parsedJson['projIsDone'],
        projTasks: List<Task>.from(
            parsedJson['projTasks'].map((x) => Task.fromJson(x))));
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      "projTitle": this.projTitle,
      "projDeadline": this.projDeadline.toIso8601String(),
      "projProgress": this.projProgress,
      "projDesc": this.projDesc,
      "projIsDone": this.projIsDone,
      "projTasks": jsonEncode(this.projTasks)
    };
  }
}

class ProjectList {
  List<Project> items = [];

  ProjectList({required this.items});

  toJson() {
    return items.map((item) {
      return item.toJson();
    }).toList();
  }
}
```

Then, in a `FutureBuilder` I'm trying to load that encoded JSON from local storage:

```dart
FutureBuilder(
                        future: storage.ready,
                        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                          if (snapshot.hasData) {
                            if (!initialized) {
                              var items = storage.getItem('projects');
                              if (items != null) {
                                sprojs.items = List<Project>.from(
                                    items.map((x) => Project.fromJson(x)));
                              }
                            }
                            initialized = true;

                            return Expanded(
                                child: ListView(
                                    children: _getProjectsWidgets(
                                        _displayDone, sprojs.items)));
                          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                            return Text("${snapshot.error}");
                          }
                          return CircularProgressIndicator();

                          
                        }),
```

And the problem is the `map` function, that is supposedly called on `null`, when the error clearly says, that the receiver is `[]`. That receiver is the `projTasks: []` from the empty project from the above (when I initialized it with a sample `Task` object, the receiver in the error changed to something like this `Receiver: "[{\"taskTitle\":\"aaa\",\"taskProgress\":0,\"taskDesc\":\"aaa\",\"taskIsDone\":false,\"taskTags\":\"[\\\"#aaa\\\"]\"}]"`).
I don't know what to do. This is a web app and it doesn't seem like there are another ways to write and read JSON.
What is wrong here? Wrong encoding? I can't spot the mistake.

Stack:

```
[        ] C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 236:49      throw_
[   +4 ms] C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 721:3   defaultNoSuchMethod
[   +1 ms] C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/core_patch.dart 61:12                 noSuchMethod
[   +1 ms] C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 716:31  noSuchMethod
[   +1 ms] C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 270:9   _checkAndCall
[   +1 ms] C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 388:10  callMethod
[   +1 ms] C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 392:5   dsend
[   +1 ms] packages/zrub/classes.dart 66:37                                                                                               fromJson
[   +1 ms] packages/zrub/projects.dart 257:62                                                                                             <fn>
[   +1 ms] C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/internal/iterable.dart 412:31                                        elementAt
```

Thank you.

Edit:
While debugging I saw `items` value after calling `storage.getItem('projects')`, and it seems strange.

`_JsonMap ({projTitle: empty project, projDeadline: 2021-06-20T20:28:47.149, projProgress: 0, projDesc: description..., projIsDone: false, projTasks: [{"taskTitle":"aaa","taskProgress":0,"taskDesc":"aaa","taskIsDone":false,"taskTags":"[\"#aaa\"]"}]})`.
Key - value pairs from `Project` don't have quotation marks, while pairs from `Task` have.

Comment: post the top 3-5 frames from the stacktrace

Comment: @pskink Ok, I added it to the post. I hope this is what you asked for